# nestjs Unable to connect to the database

Tags: node.js, docker, graphql, nestjs, typeorm

I am writing quiz api and I have problem with connection to the postgres database

app.module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      autoSchemaFile: './schema.gql',
      playground: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      keepConnectionAlive: true,
      type: 'postgres',
      port: 5433,
      username: 'postgres',
      password: '12345',
      database: 'postgres',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: false,
    }),
    QuizModule,
    QuestionModule,
    AnswerModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "$POSTGRES_PORT:$POSTGRES_PORT_DOCKER"

    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - db_network

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  db_network:
```

.env:

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres

POSTGRES_URL=postgresql://postgres:12345@localhost:5432/postgres?schema=public

POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345

POSTGRES_PORT_DOCKER=5433

POSTGRES_PORT=5433
```

I dont know what is wrong but i have:

```
[Nest] 34393  - 07/10/2023, 10:16:39 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 34393  - 07/10/2023, 10:16:39 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +24ms
[Nest] 34393  - 07/10/2023, 10:16:39 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] QuizModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 34393  - 07/10/2023, 10:16:39 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] QuestionModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 34393  - 07/10/2023, 10:16:39 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AnswerModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 34393  - 07/10/2023, 10:16:39 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 34393  - 07/10/2023, 10:16:39 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] GraphQLSchemaBuilderModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 34393  - 07/10/2023, 10:16:39 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] GraphQLModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 34393  - 07/10/2023, 10:16:39 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
```

my application was working before adding entities but after removing it still doesn't work
Could the problem be caused by something other than the database connection itself?

Comment: POSTGRES_PORT_DOCKER should be 5432

Comment: now i have error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: POSTGRES_URL `POSTGRES_URL=postgresql://postgres:12345@localhost:5433/postgres?schema=public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT_DOCKER}"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - db_network

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  db_network:
```

fix POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER} to use correct variables